# Opening up Federal Trade Commission data on Safe Harbor

Tags: data-request, usa, government, federal

I would like to know how I can get access to the underlying database powering the site [safeharbor](https://safeharbor.export.gov/list.aspx)

This lists all the private companies who have agreed to comply with the [Safe Harbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_harbor) protocol for EU data protection.

Answer (score 3):

I checked out the webpage. There is a 'Export to Excel' link on the page. I tried it. It downloads a file called 'OrganizationList.xls'. But you cannot open it in Excel. I checked the contents of the file and it is an HTML table. To view the file, change the file suffix to '.html'.

As far as extracting the data, I would use a convert HTML table to CSV tool. Below is one site that I tried with this file and it appeared to do a correct conversion:

http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm